# Regular expression with optional symbols inside

Tags: regex

I need to validate phone number. It can be so if it is

```
Have + sign at start
+79231112233
Dont have + at start
79231112233
Have spaces
7 9231112233
7 923 1112233
7 923 111 22 33
Have dashes/spaces
7-923-111-22-33
7 923-111-22-33
7 923 111-22-33
Mixed
+7-923-111 22 33
```

Is it possible using regular expressions ?

Comment: Your question looks like you want someone to write a regex for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The simplest, most bang for the buck, but hardly perfect, regex would be something like this:

```
^\+?[0-9- ]+$
```

The downside is that it would accept all dashes or all spaces.

Comment: tried it in the online tester and it seems that there some problems with plus sign validation :( without plus validating this works great - ^[0-9- ]+$

Comment: @AlexeyK you need to escape the plus sign with a backslash from its regex meaning as a quantifier. The answer didn't show the backslash at first (no code block). Further you can add a word boundary to require at least one digit: [`^\+?\b[\d -]+$`](https://www.regex101.com/r/ojf4qD/1)

Comment: But this will match a line just containing `-` or a space.

Comment: Thanks for the fix bobble bubble, I was sure I had entered the \.

Answer (score 2):

Besides matching optional `+` at the start and allowing space/hyphen in between the digits a phone number must have minimum # of digits e.g. `10` as per your given examples.

You can consider this regex for your examples to meet above conditions:

```
\+?(?:\d[ -]?){10,}
```

- `(?:\d[ -]?){10,}` enforces 10 or digits that are optionally followed by space or hyphen

Answer (score 1):

`\+` matches the literal +

`\+?` adding the '?' makes it optional, matching when '+' doesn't occur or occurs once

`[ -]` Matches a single character that is either a space or a '-'.  You could add a question mark on the end to make it optional (like above).

`\d` matches one digit (could be written as [0-9])

`\d{3}` matches exactly three digits

This should be enough information for you to construct a regex that works for your purpose.  You should learn more about regular expressions though so you are aware of the downsides.